# Added tag HyperLink in aspx page without GridView in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

On `MarkUp` in my aspx page form I have these two `TextBox` :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Mtl" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>    
<asp:TextBox ID="ps" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

The **HTML view** for these two `TextBox` is :

```
<input name="Mtl" type="text" value="901" readonly="readonly" id="Mtl" disabled="disabled" />    
<input name="ps" type="text" id="ps" />
```

Now I need insert next to the `TextBox` with `id` **ps** the `HyperLink` where passed in querystring the value of `TextBox` with `id` **Mtl**, the value is **901**.

I need pass this value for working in another aspx page.

I have tried this solution but the `HyperLink` is not clikable :

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HlLink" runat="server"
      NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/box.aspx?v={0}&e={1}&l={2}", "y", "IC", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Mtl").ToString())) %>'
      ImageUrl="~/Images/edit_icon.gif" Target="_blank" Text="Mtl"></asp:HyperLink>
```

In this aspx page I don't have `GridView`, maybe it does not work for this reason ?

How to do resolve this ?

Please help me, thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct since your control is not inside a gridview (or any `databound`control for that matter) that's why it will not work.

Actually, `<%# %>` is called data bind expressions and they are evaluated for data bound controls only. For your `HyperLink` control to work with this code nugget you will have to explicitly call the [DataBind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d(v=vs.110).aspx) method on that control like this:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HlLink.DataBind();      
}
```

Comment: thanks, but now I have this error `Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control. `

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq - Opps didn't saw you are using an `Eval` there. What is `Mtl` ? Are you getting that from _querystring_?

Comment: `Mtl` is the value `Mtl.Text = MtlFromDb.ToString();` extract from an sql  `query`

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq - Okay in that case you can directly use `Mtl.Text` instead of `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Mtl").ToString())` but please note whatever value you will have at initial page load only that value will be passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a jQuery 'Change' event on your textbox. And in this event you can set correct navigation url by picking up the value from the textbox and appending it in appropriate place in your query string. Its a fairly easy solution. If you don't know how to do it I can provide you a sample.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know much on `jQuery`